# Need some insights regarding Shunts for ammeters

Tags: shunt, power-meter

So i bought this cheap digital ammeter that can measure current from 0 - 100A:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/141196910898

I will be using this with my LM317 (1.5A max). 0-100A version was the only one left in stock. Stupid as i am i didn't read much about ammeters since i first thought that it was like a multimeter, break the circuit, put in the ammeter and you're good to go, but when i got the ammeter and i noticed how small it really was my first thought was

(there is NO WAY that this small thing can get 100A through it without melting).

So after a bit of seaching on the web i found out that you need this thing called a "shunt", Where i live shunts are pretty expensive to buy and if i order one from ebay (china) i have to wait forever for it to arrive because of the slow shipping.

I searched for different ways to make your own shunt but i couldn't really get the hang of it, so is there another solution for me to hook up this meter so that it can read up to 1.5A without a shunt? Or does anyone know a good step by step guide which shows you how to make one? Cheers.

Comment: You still haven't accepted answers for any of your previous questions on this site, despite promising to do so. You might think about fixing that given that people have given freely of their time to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That thing, as you purchased, is probably (I say probably because the information does not seem to be there) a voltmeter that indicates 0-100 for 0-50mV in.

Since an LM317 can't handle more than about 1A anyway, it was a bit silly of you to buy a 100A meter. All it would be able to do is to display 0.0 to 1.0, which is less than 10% of reading in resolution.

You can use a resistor across the input of 50m\$\Omega\$ (rather than 1/100 of that) to give 0-1A display (be sure to actually read and follow the wiring diagrams in the eBay ad that show the shunt in the **low** side before you apply power). It should be connected in the [Kelvin manner](http://www.texascomponents.com/store/KelvinConnection.asp)- high current flows through the outer leads, inner leads go to the meter:

[image]

If you can't find a resistor of that value, you can make a really crappy 50m\$\Omega\$ resistor with about 6" of AWG 30 copper wire. It will change with temperature, in particular. Move one of the connection points along the wire until it agrees with your multimeter at 1A or so.

You may be able to find some jumpers on the meter to add or move the decimal point position.

Comment: So stupid of me.. i actually didn't think that just because i bought a 0-100A meter it wouldn't be less accurate.. since it has 3 digets. i thought it would show from 0.1 to  99.9 Amps. But well you learn from your mistakes and it wasn't expensive anyway. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hey, you're probably right- it would read from 0.1 to 99.9, but that's still pretty lousy resolution (10% resolution for your current). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh alright then, I don't mind, 0.1 to 99.9 amps is fine for me. The thing that i want to have very accurate is the voltage and i bought a more expensive one for that (and should also be much simplier to wire). Just curious, if i where to plug in this ammeter without a shunt, would it still work if it doesn't get to hot?

Comment: As it is it's just a voltmeter I believe, so it will read overrange and your circuit will not work. You need some kind of resistor ("shunt" is just a name for a special kind of resistor with 4 leads = Kelvin connection) across the input. A 100A shunt is about 0.5m\$\Omega\$, if I am right about the scale, so a 50m\$\Omega\$ resistor would give reading of 0.0 to 99.9 (ignore decimal point) for 0mA to 999mA. The 'ammeter' just reads the *voltage* across the external resistor (shunt) which is what actually conducts the current.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see if i have a resistor that small, or else i might try the "wire method" you mentioned. Cheers!

Comment: Just to be sure,  50m ohm. Are we talking mega or milliohm? hehe

Comment: milli! 9 orders of magnitude is important. Ohm's law E = I * R. R = 0.05, so E = 1A * 0.05 ohm = 50mV.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again! I was asking because i tried to measure the resistance of some copper speaker wires. And i got like 10 million ohms in result.. It didn't matter how long/thick the wire was.. got a very high value.

Comment: Then your wire or your meter is done broke.

Comment: Well, it does work fine for measuring resistors etc. I just tried it to be sure, also tried with another multimeter but it still shows a high value.. This is very weird, i also took out the copper wire around an inductor. Same thing there haha

Comment: @Xane, there could be some sort of clear coating on the wire that's blocking the electric current from entering the wire, that would cause those high readings.

Comment: I just checked and you are totally right. I took some sandpaper on the end of the wire and checked again, now it is showing the right reading. Thank you!!

Comment: I just tested with a few resistors in parallel as shunt and got 55mohm. 516 mA showed 52.3 on the ammeter. I thought that it would at least show 0.52 or something similar

Comment: @Xane That's Xactly what I said it would show! If you want 00.5 use 0.5m ohm- about 6" of AWG 10 wire. Or figure out how to change the fixed decimal point (probably a resistor position).

Comment: Oh sorry then i missunderstood, my bad. Alright i will look and maybe contact the seller if it is possible to switch decimal point! :)

Comment: Forgot to add, this is what the meter looks like from behind: 
https://i.gyazo.com/32684cd102104f2c0f4b0270863bcc3e.jpg

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany i think i did the same mistake with a voltmeter as i did with my ammeter. I bought a 0-100V voltmeter: 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/141690229302
I just tried it, and i thought that i would show 3 digits always, for example if i measure 1.25v it will show all the 3 digits = 1.25v, but instead it shows 1.2v only, if i increase the voltage to 10 volt THEN it shows 10.0 volt = all 3 digits. i can't find any resistor etc on the back to fix this, only a small pot which calibrates it, Is it still possible to change the decimals or do i have to buy a new one?

Comment: picture of meter: https://i.gyazo.com/bfa6bb6188c1c45d8e2c274574ccaddf.jpg

Comment: UPDATE: Just wanted to inform you all that i made my own shunt with a small piece of wood and som steel wire, works perfectly. I could never do it without your help and tips, so i thank you all! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is to get a real multimeter.  You really shouldn't expect something that costs $3.35 to do what even a mediocre $20 multimeter can do.

However, to answer your question, a shunt is just a resistor.  Resistors are current to voltage converters by Ohms law:

Volts = Amps * Ohms

Of course there is a tradeoff here.  Generally you want a measurement to perturb whatever you're measuring as little as possible.  In this case, the voltage across the shunt is voltage taken away from the device.  You make the resistance low to minimize this voltage.  On the other hand, too low a voltage is hard to measure accurately or with little noise.

Most ordinary ammeters select a shunt that causes about 100 mV for whatever the full scale current is.  That's not too hard to measure with three digits of accuracy, especially when you get the user to manually adjust the zero offset for you.

At large currents like 100 A, a different technique is usually used.  This is because with the shunt adjusted to about the same resulting voltage, the power the shunt must dissipate is proportional to the voltage.  100 A at 100 mV is 10 W.  That would require a deliberate power resistor, and you then have to worry about the resistance change over temperature.

Large currents cause enough of a magnetic field around them that it becomes feasible to measure that instead of trying to cause a deliberate voltage drop.  High current meters therefore are usually just a fat wire with a Hall affect sensor nearby.  It's unlikely that's what's in your $3.35 meter, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you mean a real multimeter or a real ammeter? Because the multimeter i have is not a very cheap one.

Comment: Multimeter implies that ammeter is one of its functions.